# Node.js Soap method params parsed as string instead of related object

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

I'm using node-soap to consume a WebService. I've used this library and consumed this service many times before, but this time I'm having the following situation.

I create the client using the WSDL that contains the methods, inputs etc:

```
const soap = require("soap");

const url = "https://servintp.latinoseguros.com.mx:8071/wsCotizadorAutos/cotizador/CotizadorLatino.svc?wsdl";
soap.createClient(url, {}, (error, client) => {
    if (error) {
        callback(error);
    } else {
      const describe = client.describe()["CotizadorLatino"]["BasicHttpBinding_ICotizadorLatino"];
      console.log(describe["ObtenerMarcas"])
   }
});
```

The request is successful and the client is created, but when I describe the method "ObtenerMarcas" I receive the following object:

```
{
  input: { datos: 'q17:DatosRequeridos' },
  output: { ObtenerMarcasResult: 'q18:ListMarca' }
}
```

Whose only input param shows as only a String, while it should be an object whith different objects and attributes.

When using [Soap Client](http://www.soapclient.com) and inputing the exact same WSDL endpoint, the method is described as it should, with all the children and attributes that are expected to be passed:

[Soap Client Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1HkY.png)

Which makes me believe that this has something to do with the client configuration or probably something very basic that I'm not taking into account.

Can anybody point me on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!